# Web Scraping tagged Questions with Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Hi I have the following spider:

```
import scrapy

class TREC_spider(scrapy.Spider):

    "use this spider to obtain the proper tagged questions from http://cogcomp.org/Data/QA/QC/"

    name = "TREC"
    start_urls = ["http://cogcomp.org/Data/QA/QC/train_5500.label"]

    def parse(self,response):
        for question in response.selector.xpath("/html/body/pre/text()"):
            yield question
```

I turned the robots.txt thing to False, but I still get the following text on my prompt:

```
2018-12-25 14:02:06 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-12-25 14:02:06 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-12-25 14:02:06 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on <inserrt adress here>
2018-12-25 14:02:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://cogcomp.org/Data/QA/QC/train_5500.label> (referer: None)
2018-12-25 14:02:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

How can I get my spider to actually crawl the page?

Comment: That `Crawled (200)` means it _did_ fetch the document, and it came back `200 OK`. In the future, a little debugging on your own would go a long way; try `self.log("response = %s", response)` to observe that the `parse()` is called as expected

Answer (score 1):

you need to return items or dictionaries, try changing `yield question` to:

```
yield {'question': question.extract_first()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath doesn't match because the `response` is actually a `TextResponse`. That URL does not return HTML it returns `text/plain`.

You will likely want `yield response.body_as_unicode()` or to actually chop up the lines in the response before yielding them as structured data